# Open new gnome-terminal and run command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a script that opens a new terminal then runs a separate python script from that terminal.

I've tried:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal 'python f.py'")
```

and

```
p = Popen("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("python f.py")
```

but both methods only open a new terminal and do not run `f.py`.  How would I go about opening the terminal AND running a separate script?

Edit:
I would like to open a new terminal window because `f.py` is a simply server that is running `serve_forever()`.  I'd like the original terminal window to stay "free" to run other commands.

Comment: you don't need to open terminal, just call your python with popen with the arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: try `p.communicate("python f.py\n")`

Comment: can't you run `python f.py &` then? do you need output from `p.py` ?

Comment: Oh interesting, this is the first time I've seen the `&` flag.  I suppose this accomplishes what I'm after.

Comment: ok, I have edited my answer. I think it pretty much covers every aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like most terminals, gnome terminal needs [options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) to execute commands:

```
gnome-terminal [-e, --command=STRING] [-x, --execute]
```

You probably need to add `-x` option:

> x, --execute
>
> Execute the remainder of the command line inside the terminal.

so:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -x python f.py")
```

That would not run your process in the background unless you add `&` to your command line BTW.

The `communicate` attempt would need a newline for your input but should work too, but complex processes like terminals don't "like" being redirected. It seems like using an interactive tool backwards.
And again, that would block until termination. What *could* work would be to use `p.stdin.write("python f.py\n")` to give control to the python script. But in that case it's unlikely to work.

So it seems that you don't even need python do to what you want. You just need to run

```
python f.py &
```

in a shell.

Answer (score 2):

As of `GNOME Terminal 3.24.2 Using VTE version 0.48.4 +GNUTLS -PCRE2`

> Option “-x” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
>   Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.

Thus the preferred syntax appears to be

```
gnome-terminal -- echo hello
```

rather than

```
gnome-terminal -x echo hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example of how you would call a executable python file with `subprocess.call` Using `argparse` to properly parse the input.

the target process will print your given input.

**Your python file to be called:**

```
import argparse    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--file", help="Just A test", dest='myfile')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.myfile
```

**Your calling python file:**

```
from subprocess import call


#call(["python","/users/dev/python/sandboxArgParse.py", "--file", "abcd.txt"])
call(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "python /users/dev/python/sandboxArgParse.py --file abcd.txt"])
```

> **Just for information:** 
>   You probably don't need python calling another python script to run a terminal window with a process, but could do as follows:

```
gnome-terminal -e "python /yourfile.py -f yourTestfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I clarified my question as the python script I'm calling is a simple server utilizing `serve_forever()`.  Therefore, I'd like to run the script in a new terminal window so that my current terminal isn't tied up.

Comment: That's easy just use call with `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will open a new terminal and execute the process:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    "sudo gnome-terminal -x python f.py", 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=None,
    shell=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running a uWS server with this.In my case **Popen** didn't help(Even though it  run the executable, still it couldn't communicate with a client -: socket connection is broken).This is working.Also now they recommends to use "--" instead of "-e".

```
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', "--", "python3", "server_deployment.py"])
```

#server_deployment.py

```
def run():
    execution_cmd = "./my_executable arg1 arg2 dll_1 dll_2"
    os.system(execution_cmd)
run()
```