# How do I input strings in Linux terminal that points to file path using subprocess.call command?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm using Ubuntu and have been trying to do a simple automation that requires me to input the [name of website] and the [file path] onto a list of command lines. I'm using subprocess and call function. I tried something simpler first using the "ls" command.

```
from subprocess import call
text = raw_input("> ")
("ls", "%s") % (text)
```

These returned as "buffsize must be an integer". I tried to found out what it was and apparently I had to pass the command as a list. So I tried doing it on the main thing im trying to code.

```
from subprocess import call
file_path = raw_input("> ")
site_name = raw_input("> ")
call("thug", -FZM -W "%s" -n "%s") % (site_name, file_path)
```

These passed as an invalid syntax on the first "%s". Can anyone point me to the correct direction?

Comment: I've answered almost the same question today and provided an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518944/open-new-gnome-terminal-and-run-command/47519082#47519082

Comment: Why do you keep trying to apply `%` to a `tuple`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `%` on a tuple.

```
("ls", "%s") % text   # Broken
```

You probably mean

```
("ls", "%s" % text)
```

But just `"%s" % string` is obviously going to return simply `string`, so there is no need to use formatting here.

```
("ls", text)
```

This still does nothing useful; did you forget the `call`?

You also cannot have unquoted strings in the argument to `call`.

```
call("thug", -FZM -W "%s" -n "%s") % (site_name, file_path)  # broken
```

needs to have `-FZM` and `-W` quoted, and again, if you use format strings, the formatting needs to happen adjacent to the format string.

```
call(["thug", "-FZM", "-W", site_name, "-n", file_path])
```

Notice also how the first argument to `call()` is either a proper list, or a long single string (in which case you need `shell=True`, which you want to [avoid if you can](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)).

If you are writing new scripts, you most definitely should be thinking *seriously* about targetting Python 3 (in which case you want to pivot to `subprocess.run()` and `input()` instead of `raw_input()` too).  Python 2 is already past its originally announced end-of-life date, though it was pushed back a few years because Py3k adoption was still slow a few years ago.  It no longer is, and shouldn't be -- you want to be in Py3, that's where the future is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of how you would call a executable python file with `subprocess.call` Using `argparse` to properly parse the input.

**Your python file to be called (sandboxArgParse.py):**

```
import argparse    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--filePath", help="Just A test", dest='filePath')
parser.add_argument("--siteName", help="Just A test", dest='siteName')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.siteName
print args.filePath
```

**Your calling python file:**

```
from subprocess import call


call(["python","/users/dev/python/sandboxArgParse.py", "--filePath", "abcd.txt", "--siteName", "www.google.com"])
```

Comment: I completely agree that parsing command-line arguments is **way** better than interactive input, but I don't think this answer is going to help the OP.

Comment: :D That's why he have you @tripleee!. I'm giving an alternative solution that is cleaner. Your answer will probably solve the problem, my answer might be a motivation to do things with beauty.